# Is this an adequate definition of the natural numbers in terms of elementary set theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, definition

Is this an adequate definition of the natural numbers?

The term *number* is synonymous with *natural number* in this context.  The terms *front* and *back* are used in order to avoid using numbers *first* and *second* to define numbers.

*$1$ is a number.*

*The set $\mathbb{N}$ of numbers is the exactly that set of elements appearing as front elements in the pairs of the succession of numbers defined as follows:*

*The succession of numbers is the set of ordered pairs of numbers including every number exactly once as a front element, and every number other than 1 exactly once as a back element. If $n$ is a front number then the back number, called the successor of $n,$ is denoted $n^\prime$*

[Added to address a flaw pointed out in the answer posted by Greg Martin.]

*Every number $n$ uniquely terminates a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (called the segment $\mathbb{S}_n$), such that $1$ is in $\mathbb{S}_n$ and $\mathbb{S}_n$ includes the successor of each of its members other than $n$.*

*For every number $n$ we define the segment $\mathbb{S}_n^\prime = \mathbb{S}_n\cup{n^\prime}$*

*We define $\mathbb{S}_1=\left\{1\right\}$*

The proposed definition is intended to use a minimum of concepts.  My motivation is that I find definitions using variables and other concepts to beg the question of what those concepts really mean.  The variable $n$ was used for brevity, and in the simplest possible way.

This is the definition of the natural numbers I use as the standard:

From [Fundamentals of Mathematics Foundations of Mathematics: The Real Number System and Algebra](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262520935/)

> I. $1$ is a number.
> II. To every number $a$ there corresponds a unique number $a^{\prime},$ called its successor.
> III. If $a^{\prime}=b^{\prime},$ then $a=b$.
> IV. $a^{\prime}\ne 1$ for every number $a$.
> V. Let $A\left(x\right)$ be a proposition containing the variable $x$. If $A\left(1\right)$ holds and if $A\left(n^{\prime}\right)$ follows from $A\left(n\right)$ for every number $n$, then $A\left(x\right)$ holds for every number $x.$

The first four rules amount to sayin the successor function is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}-\left\{1\right\}$ That is what my long-winded discussion of ordered pairs was intended to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written this is circular, although I suspect it could be rewritten to not be circular. However, note that if any set $S$ satisfies the second part of the definition, then so (for example) does $S \cup \{ (x,y), (y,x) \}$ where $x,y$ are any objects that are not elements of $S$. There are many such extensions of $S$ and so this definition doesn't define the natural numbers uniquely. The missing piece is some sort of induction/well-ordering statement that guarantees that every natural number can be found in a sequence of ordered pairs that contains $1$.

Comment: So I need a rule to exclude the appearance pair and its converse.  I'm not certain about the circularity issue.  The way I'm thinking about it is that prior to sequencing, the elements have only the property of being distinct.  So it doesn't matter which element we select as the successor of 1, for example.

Comment: Would an induction rule be part of the definition or a test of the definition?  Every definition I know of for the natural numbers includes an induction rule.  But that seems to be a way to make the definition useful, rather than a definition of the set itself.

Comment: OK, I get it.  I think that is explained in something I read, but I didn’t fully understand.  I'm working on a fix.

Comment: Aha, I think we've found the issue: The induction rule is absolutely an essential part of the definition of the natural numbers. Another set that satisfies your definition (and I–IV of the standard definition) is $\Bbb N$ together with any number of disjoint copies of $\Bbb Z$.